# Trouble reading String Length

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was trying to grab the string length of readData but when I try msgbox(readData.Length),
its giving me a large numeric digit instead. Anyone care to help? Thanks.

```
Dim readData as string
serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)
                Dim returndata As String = _
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
                readData = "" + returndata
                msg()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the return value of Stream.Read, and only create the string from the bytes that have actually been read:

```
Dim bytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)
Dim text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesRead)
```

Note, however, that you should *usually* keep reading from a stream until there's no more data to read. `StreamReader` can help you do this really simply, if you're trying to convert everything to a string:

```
Dim text = new StreamReader(serverStream, Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd()
```

(I'm assuming you're closing the stream elsewhere; alternatively you should close the `StreamReader` in a finally block.)

Are you absolutely sure that the data will always be ASCII, by the way? That means you'll never get any accented characters etc.

If anything is still unclear after reading mine and Guffa's answers, please post more details of *exactly* what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the quite common mistake of ignoring the return value from the `Read` method.

The method will read data into the buffer, and return the number of bytes that was placed in the buffer. By ignoring that return value and decoding the entire buffer, the string will be as long as the buffer, and contain a lot of garbage data at the end.

Also, you have to call the `Read` method repeatedly until it returns zero, as the method doesn't have to return all the data in one call.

```
Dim readData As string
Dim length As Integer = 0
Dim size As Integer
Do
  size = serverStream.Read(inStream, length, buffSize - length)
  length += size
Loop Until size = 0
readData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, length)

MessageBox.Show(length.ToString())
MessageBox.Show(readData.Length.ToString())
```

As you are using the ASCII encoding, `length` and `readData.Length` will be the same, as each byte is decoded into one character. If you were using for example the UTF-8 encoding they could differ, as `length` would be the number of bytes read and `readData.Length` would be the number of character that those bytes were decoded into.

Comment: That's still only going to read *up to* `buffSize` bytes, of course - it's not going to keep going until there's no data left. If the aim is to keep reading everything and the server will disconnect, he'd need to keep reading after filling the buffer. If the server *isn't* going to disconnect, then reading until the buffer is filled is *also* potentially going to hang. Unless the buffer size has been specified *by* the server, of course.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, that is a good point. The code assumes that the buffer is always large enough to hold all the data.